# c3p0, MySQL, and Java 8 fails to connect

Tags: c3p0

I am trying to upgrade a project from Java 7 to Java 8 and cannot seem to get c3p0 to handle the migration. It appears that c3p0 is getting stuck waiting for a connection to MySQL and so my web application just hangs forever when it hits line 1459 in the BasicResourcePool class: 'this.wait(timeout);'. My project runs fine in Java 7. I have tried updating the MySQL-connector jar to 5.1.33 and have updated c3p0 to 0.9.5-pre9.

I can only assume that Java 8 changed JDBC connection handling and thus I need to change something. This is how I am setting up the MySQL connection. I have verified that all of the values from the property file are being grabbed correctly.

```
properties = Locator.getInternalProperties(Locator.MYSQL_PROPERTIES);
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + Locator.getValue(properties, Locator.HOST) + "/"
    + Locator.getValue(properties, Locator.SCHEMA)
    + "?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
cpds.setUser(Locator.getValue(properties, Locator.USER));
String password = EncryptionUtils.decrypt(Locator.getValue(properties, Locator.PASSWORD));
cpds.setPassword(password);
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(50);
cpds.setMaxStatements(200);
cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
cpds.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
```

I am not sure what else I can try at this point.

Here is a thread dump from Java 8:

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-9@8497" daemon prio=5 tid=0x52 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1459)
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:639)
      at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:549)
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
      at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
      at com.attensity.saascore.shared.dao.BaseDao.getConnection(BaseDao.java:24)
      at com.attensity.saascore.shared.dao.UserDao.getUserByUsernameAndPassword(UserDao.java:46)
      at com.attensity.saascore.shared.manager.UserManager.getUserByUsernameAndPassword(UserManager.java:92)
      at com.attensity.saascore.shared.manager.AuthenticationManager.authenticateUser(AuthenticationManager.java:60)
      at com.attensity.saascore.rest.user.service.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:112)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
      at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
      at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
      - locked <0x2478> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: hi, can you post a Thread dump of your VM while it has been hanging a while? many thanks.

Comment: Added to my original post

Comment: oh... i need more, so much more. what's of interest here isn't what the wait()ing thread is doing -- it's wait()ing, but whether other threads are trying to acquire new Connections to satisfy. those would be the threads c3p0 names "helper threads". also of interest is whether your application is reliably close()ing Connections. the hang you are seeing looks like pool exhaustion following a Connection leak. so if something has changed in how your app works under Java 8 that renders your Connection cleanup strategy less reliable, that would explain in.

Comment: ( one thing to try is the c3p0 settings `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients )

Comment: After much more testing I found a band-aid solution to my problem. See my answer below. I figured you would need more info than what I posted but I was in a meeting and couldn't post more at the time.

Comment: thanks. it's helpful. in your basic JDBC test, a call to DriverManager.getConnection() timed out quickly? (c3p0 should be able to deal with that no problem, things only get hard if the call hangs indefinitely.)

Comment: Yes, the call to DriverManager.getConnection() does not time out right away but does after 15-20 seconds. I have set my 'hosts matching' in MySQL to % so it should accept a connection from anywhere but localhost still fails. There is some issue with Java 8, MySQL, and localhost on my Mac. Without testing further I can't say if it is specific to me or a larger issue. This scenario unfortunately causes c3p0 to just hang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears my issue has to do with Java 8 and localhost for MySQL. I created a new super simple project to test c3p0. Again, Java 7 worked without issue but Java 8 did not. I then created a super basic JDBC application and Java 7 worked and Java 8 did not but I could actually see an error saying that my connection was refused. c3p0 is not handling the connection refused appropriately so the connection thread is just hanging forever. I did in fact test that by just letting my application run overnight to see if I eventually get a connection timeout in c3p0 but I did not.

Finally I created a user connection in MySQL using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and changed my connection URL to be 127.0.0.1 and magically my JDBC test worked. I then tested c3p0 with the 127.0.0.1 connection and it worked. I did not dig into why localhost works fine in Java 7 but not Java 8. Hopefully changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my production environment for MySQL will not be an issue.

If you would like me to help troubleshoot anything or do more testing I would be happy to do so. For now I am going to move on. Hopefully someone smarter than me has a better solution.